# How to let visual studio 2015 custom wizard substitute $var$ in code

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio, wizard

I'm stuck with creating a custom wizard in VS 2015.

To be honest, what I did is creating a custom wizard project by choosing *File -> New... Project*, then select *Templates/Visual C++/General/Custom Wizard* and click *OK*.

It is pretty difficult to get some useful information from the msdn websites and I could not find anything similiar on SO regarding the following.

Q: How can I change the *default.js* script, such that my customed variable $somevar$ is being replaced upon creation with a string entered by the user on the wizard html page?

The wizard shall include a file `test.c` which consists of a function definition like this:

```
int test_$somevar$_func() { return 0; }
```

When a user enters the string `foo` the resulting code in the newly created project shall be

```
int test_foo_func() { return 0; }
```

[EDIT]

The included ReadMe.txt gives a hint about referencing content from the dialog boxes using `[!output PROJECT_NAME]`.

Comment: learn create method https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhceedxx.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I finally found and tried out successfully [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37882537/6463480) for string manipulation and substituting in my template files.