# Remove dot from VS template $safeprojectname$

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-templates

Is there a possibility to remove a dot from the `$projectname$` or `$safeprojectname$` parameters in VS template?

I want to use the cleaned project name as part of a class name. `$safeprojectname$` only removes `:\/*?"<>|`

Maybe it is possible to do custom transformations on these parameters?

Comment: No, this is built-in automagic. Just do this the other way around, substitute the dot with (say) an underscore when you generate the class name.  Not the only issue btw, "123" is a valid project name.

Comment: On the other hand I wanted to use a dot as a namespace separator. But I think I will go for naming the class in a general way without taking the project name into consideration. It will suffice our needs. Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio Templates - custom parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37395075/visual-studio-templates-custom-parameters)